# Single MySQL table into multidimensional JSON with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a table in my database called `timeline_entries`. This table contains the following fields:
`id`, `headline`, `text`, `startDate`, `type`, `media`, `caption`, `credit`. The `id` field is used for referencing individual entries through a CMS.

I have worked out how to export the data as JSON and save to a file, but I'm struggling to find a way to format it into the following structure;

```
    {
"timeline":
{
    "headline":"value",
    "type":"default",
    "startDate":"value",
    "text":"value",
    "asset":
               {
                   "media":"value",
                   "credit":"value",
                   "caption":"value"
               },
    "date": [
        {
            "startDate":"value",
            "type":"",
            "headline":"value",
            "text":"value",
            "asset":
               {
                   "media":"value",
                   "credit":"value",
                   "caption":"value"
               }
        },
        {
            "startDate":"value",
            "type":"",
            "headline":"value",
            "text":"value",
            "asset":
               {
                   "media":"value",
                   "credit":"value",
                   "caption":"value"
               }
        },
        {
            "startDate":"value",
            "type":"",
            "headline":"value",
            "text":"value",
            "asset":
            {
                "media":"value",
                "credit":"value",
                "caption":"value"
            }
        },
    ]
}
    }
```

(Please ignore the shoddy indenting, I'm still getting used to this!)

I've had to replace the actual data with 'value' as some of the data is quite long.

As you can see, the first set of data needs to be formatted slightly different to the rest, the remainder of the sets placed within "date" and then the `media`, `caption` and `credit` fields need to be structured as a subset of "asset".

There will be more rows of data than just four or so, so I can't hardcode anything.

Can anyone help me format it? If it's possible, I'd like to keep the database side as simple as possible, but it can be changed if I have to. Perhaps I'm going about this completely wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting of JSON isn't at all important other than for aesthetics, have you thought of just using the php [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method and have done with it?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Yeah, I thought that initially, but the project I'm working on is an administrative interface for this - http://timeline.verite.co/ to help avoid having to edit the .json file each time I want to add new items.

It's quite picky about the format of the JSON data, and I felt it would be easier to format the data than try and hack it to read another format. My Javascript skills are quite poor when it comes to that sort of thing!